# awk: 0602-562 Field $() is not correct. in a ksh script on AIX

Tags: awk, aix

I have a text file that has information for several locations.  Each new section in the file has a header.  I am trying to take all the information under a single header, strip out the header, and move it to a separate file.  All sections move to a separate file based on header information.  I am programming this in a shell script using ksh running on aix.

```
awk '/FILE-HDRPQ/{x=substr ($0,11,6)}NR>1{print $0 > $TRANSDIR"/"x"_prchgrpt.txt";}' $TRANSDIR/$prcfile
```

FILE-HDRPQ is the first part of the header.  $0 contains all columns from that header until the line before the next header. x=an identifying number in the header which is used to create the filename that $0 (minus the top header line) will dump into.

Variables $TRANSDIR and $prcfile help us name the file and place it in the proper directory.  These variables are called out earlier in the script.

I am now getting

> awk: 0602-562 Field $() is not correct.

when I run the script.  Can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong.  I have tried playing with single and double quotes.

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem please indicate so with the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 2):

***awk*** is always trying to interpret `$<something>` as a field value (e.g. `$0` - the whole record, `$3` - the third field, `$NF` - the last field value)

Pass directory name via variable:

```
awk -v dir="$TRANSDIR" '/FILE-HDRPQ/{x=substr ($0,11,6)}
       NR>1{print $0 > dir"/"x"_prchgrpt.txt";}' "$TRANSDIR/$prcfile"
```

Comment: You are awesome - I was looking at the wrong var.  Thanks so much.

Comment: @GingerBeard76, you're welcome

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the TRANSDIR variable to awk explicitly, like that:

```
awk -v TRANSDIR="$TRANSDIR"
```

and then use it like this:

```
print $0 > TRANSDIR
```

inside the awk script.

Comment: You guys are amazing - I was barking up the wrong tree trying to figure out what was wrong with $0 - thanks so much.  Saved my bacon today.  Free internets all around!